# How do I get the value of a JQuery plugin attribute so I can set it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, plugins

I'm playing around with a simple Jquery plugin called 'Water Bubble' available [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Customizable-Liquid-Bubble-Chart-With-jQuery-Canvas.html). I created it using a call like this:

```
$('#demo-1').waterbubble({
    waterColor: 'orange',
    textColor: '#fff',
    txt: 'OJ',
    font: '40px Segoe UI, serif',
    wave: false,
    animation: true,
    radius: 150,
    data: 0.2,
});
```

Now when I click on the rendered plugin (a canvas, in this case), I want the value (0.2) to increment to 0.3. So I created a click handler for all canvases.

```
$( "canvas" ).click(function() {
  var temp1 = $(this.id); // Gives me the correct ID
  var temp2 = $(this.id).waterbubble.data; // Doesn't work
});
```

How can I get the value of the 'data' field, so I can set it again to 0.3, 0.4 and so on? If the animation persists, that'd just be the cherry on top.

Comment: can you share a demo?

Comment: All depends on the plug-in

Comment: Could you instead just increment a variable and then set the data value?

Comment: Will, I could do that. Since I will have multiple bubbles, I was hoping to avoid the overhead of saving variables.

Comment: Okay I just tried that but I can't set the data value alone. I have to save other attributes as well, or it just reverts to all default values. Even the animation starts from zero :( Is there a way to set just the data value independent of the others?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.waterbubble()` again with updated `data` value.

run the code below, click to increase water level

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var setting = {
    waterColor: 'orange',
    textColor: '#fff',
    txt: 'OJ',
    font: '40px Segoe UI, serif',
    wave: false,
    animation: true,
    radius: 150,
    data: 0.1,
  };

  $('#demo-1')
    .data('waterbubble.setting', setting)
    .waterbubble(setting)
    .on('click', function() {
      var setting = $(this).data('waterbubble.setting');
      setting.data = Math.min(1, setting.data + 0.1);
      $(this).waterbubble(setting);
    });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Customizable-Liquid-Bubble-Chart-With-jQuery-Canvas/waterbubble.js"></script>

<p>Click to increase water level</p>
<canvas id="demo-1"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if its perfect solution for you but I have tried to edit in the plugin and added new prototype property `getConf` to `Waterbubble`. Check your console to see `data`.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.waterbubble = function(options) {
        var config = $.extend({
            radius: 100,
            lineWidth: undefined,
            data: 0.5,
            waterColor: 'rgba(25, 139, 201, 1)',
            textColor: 'rgba(06, 85, 128, 0.8)',
            font: '',
            wave: true,
            txt: undefined,
            animation: true
        }, options);

        var canvas = this[0];
        config.lineWidth = config.lineWidth ? config.lineWidth : config.radius/24;

        var waterbubble = new Waterbubble(canvas, config);

        return this;
    }


    function Waterbubble (canvas, config) {
        this.refresh(canvas, config);
        this.getConf(config);

    }


    Waterbubble.prototype = {
        getConf: function (config) {
           var data = config.data;
            console.log(data);

        },

        refresh: function (canvas, config) {
            canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            this._init(canvas, config)
        },

        _init: function (canvas, config){
            var radius = config.radius;
            var lineWidth = config.lineWidth;

            canvas.width = radius*2 + lineWidth;
            canvas.height = radius*2 + lineWidth;

            this._buildShape(canvas, config);
        },

        _buildShape: function (canvas, config) {

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var gap = config.lineWidth*2;
            //raidus of water
            var r = config.radius - gap;
            var data = config.data;
            var lineWidth = config.lineWidth

            var waterColor = config.waterColor;
            var textColor = config.textColor;
            var font = config.font;

            var wave = config.wave

            // //the center of circle
            var x = config.radius + lineWidth/2;
            var y = config.radius + lineWidth/2;

            ctx.beginPath();

            ctx.arc(x, y, config.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = waterColor;
            ctx.stroke();
            //if config animation true
            if (config.animation) {
                this._animate(ctx, r, data, lineWidth, waterColor, x, y, wave)
            } else {
                this._fillWater(ctx, r, data, lineWidth, waterColor, x, y, wave);
            }

            if (typeof config.txt == 'string'){
                this._drawText(ctx, textColor, font, config.radius, data, x, y, config.txt);
            }

            return;
        },

        _fillWater: function (ctx, r, data, lineWidth, waterColor, x, y, wave) {
            ctx.beginPath();

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

            //start co-ordinates
            var sy = r*2*(1 - data) + (y - r);
            var sx = x - Math.sqrt((r)*(r) - (y - sy)*(y - sy));
            //middle co-ordinates
            var mx = x;
            var my = sy;
            //end co-ordinates
            var ex = 2*mx - sx;
            var ey = sy;

            var extent; //extent

            if (data > 0.9 || data < 0.1 || !wave) {
                extent = sy
            } else{
                extent = sy - (mx -sx)/4
            }

            ctx.beginPath();

            ctx.moveTo(sx, sy)
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo((sx + mx)/2, extent, mx, my);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo((mx + ex)/2, 2*sy - extent, ex, ey);

            var startAngle = -Math.asin((x - sy)/r)
            var endAngle = Math.PI - startAngle;

            ctx.arc(x, y, r, startAngle, endAngle, false)

            ctx.fillStyle = waterColor;
            ctx.fill()
        },

        _drawText: function (ctx, textColor, font, radius, data, x, y, txt) {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

            var size = font ? font.replace( /\D+/g, '') : 0.4*radius;
            ctx.font = font ? font : 'bold ' + size + 'px Microsoft Yahei';

            txt = txt.length ? txt : data*100 + '%'

            var sy = y + size/2;
            var sx = x - ctx.measureText(txt).width/2

            ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            ctx.fillText(txt, sx, sy)
        },

        _animate: function (ctx, r, data, lineWidth, waterColor, x, y, wave) {
            var datanow = {
                value: 0
            };
            var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || function (func) {
                setTimeout(func, 16);
            };
            var self = this;
            var update = function () {
                if (datanow.value < data) {
                    datanow.value += (data - datanow.value)/15
                    self._runing = true;
                } else {
                    self._runing = false;
                }
            }
            var step = function () {
                self._fillWater(ctx, r, datanow.value, lineWidth, waterColor, x, y, wave);
                update();
                if (self._runing) {
                    requestAnimationFrame(step);
                }
            }
            step(ctx, r, datanow, lineWidth, waterColor, x, y, wave)
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```